# Launch python script based on a dynamic config file

Tags: python-3.x, config

Each morning, a config file is fed with a list of hours. Hours in the json file are different each days.

I would like a python script to be executed for each hour of the configuration file.  What is the best way to do this?

Do I have to do a loop while? What is the best practice?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a few lines from the configuration file? What does it look like? What does your program do, exactly, and how do you want to execute it?

Comment: I don't have code for now, I just want take some inputs from the community in order to write good code. The config file is just a json containing some hours like 4:00 am, 7:00 pm etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cronjob that reads the config file and executes the python scripts every morning.

Comment: Hours in the json file are different each days, so I think i can't take this way. A cronjob can maybe create new cronjob each day but I'm not sure that's a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2Cr_YRQk7o).

basically, you can schedule a python script daily that will execuetes automatically.

Comment: Hours in the json file are different each days, so I think i can't take this way.